# Cisco QinQ - More than one s-vlan on dot1q-tunnel for the same c-vlans

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, cisco-ios-15, qinq

I have a scenario where I have 3 service vlans (10,20,30) from a trunk port and need to brige our customer vlans (100,200,300,400) between all the service vlans. I need to do it all in the same switch (cat6504e s72033_rp-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M, Version 15.1(2)SY2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)).

I always tunneled customer vlans between sites doing an access port for the service vlan (access vlan XXX and mode dot1q-tunnel) and in the connected switch a trunk port as usual.

What I tried to do is selective q-in-q but seems this version does not allow selective vlan, only one to one mapping which not work in this case because I need all my vlans to go across all service vlan and really I don't know if it is suitable for this scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: That switch and line cards for it are EoS. You really need to replace it with current hardware and software. There will be no more software updates for the rest of its life (software support ended last month, and the last hardware support date for the chassis is 04/30/2024).

Comment: Yes I know  @RonMaupin , I'm now upgrading all all old stuff with nxos but this one is in a centric place and a lot of production stuff connected. With nxos I know I can do selective q-in-q but I really didn't tried to do it with multiple c-vlans between multiple s-vlan, it is possible?